# Making .gitignore ignore nested folders in tmp dir

Tags: git

This is my .gitignore file

```
.bundle
db/*.sqlite3*
log/*.log
*.log
tmp/*
doc/
*.swp
*~
.project
.DS_Store
log/*
Gemfile.lock
```

So why does it keep saying things like this:

```
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   modified:   tmp/cache/assets/E04/890/sprockets%2F2f5173deea6c795b8fdde723bb4b63af
```

i.e Why is it not ignore my tmp dir?  As the file and directory names seem to be random, I don't suppose I can add them explicitly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just put `tmp/` on a line on its own, not `tmp/*`.

Comment: Thanks.  Have done that, but it still tells me the about the tmp modifications.  Do I need to do anything to make git reread the .gitignore file?  Or do I need to delete all the tmp files from git?

Comment: Notice that it's saying "Changes not staged for commit", not "Untracked files". That means that that file is already being tracked (it's been committed at least once), and thus `.gitignore` doesn't apply. If you don't want that file tracked, then `git rm` it.

Comment: Actually, you want to run `git rm --cached file` if you only intend to remove the file from you git repo and not delete it all together.